# Ellipticity of Bott-Chern Laplacian

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, laplacian

I want to prove that Bott-Chern Laplacian
$$\tilde{\Delta}_{BC}^{p,q}=(\partial\bar\partial)(\partial\bar\partial)^*+(\partial\bar\partial)^*(\partial\bar\partial)+(\bar\partial^*\partial)(\bar\partial^*\partial)^*+(\bar\partial^*\partial)^*(\bar\partial^*\partial)+\bar\partial^*\bar\partial+\partial^*\partial$$
is elliptic.

Such operator is considered in D. Angella's book "Cohomological Aspects in Complex Non-Kähler Geometry". He makes the statement that such operator is elliptic and gives two references:

- K. Kodaira, D.C. Spencer, On deformations of complex analytic structures. III [Prop. 5]
- M. Schweitzer, Authour de la cohomologie de Bott-Chern [Sect. 2.b]

First reference, I believe, assumes that manifold is Kahler (even section is called "Stability of Kahler  metrics"). Apart from that, the whole proof of ellipticity is closed in following sentences:

> "We infer readily that the principal part of the operator $E_t$ has the form 
>   $$\sum_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta}g_i^{\bar\beta\alpha}g_i^{\bar\delta\gamma}\frac{\partial^4}{\partial z^\alpha \partial\bar{z^\beta}\partial z^\gamma \partial\bar{z^\delta}}$$
>   where $(g_i^{\bar\beta\alpha})$ is the inverse matrix of $(g_{i\alpha\bar\beta}),g_{i\alpha\bar\beta}=g_{i\alpha\bar\beta}(z_i,t).$ Thus  $E_t$ is
>   strongly elliptic."

Second reference provides deeper insight. Author first computes symbols of $\partial,\bar\partial,\partial^*\bar\partial^*$ and then just uses composition rule for symbol. However I have doubts in computation. He states that
$$(\sigma_{\partial^*}(x,\xi))_{I,J;I\setminus i,J}=(-1)^{\alpha_i}\bar{\xi_i}.$$
Which means that in coordinates symbol of $\partial^*$ is just $\pm$ contraction of $\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}_i}.$

Here few my fuzzy remarks which indicates that something is wrong:

Given hermitian metric $h$ we have that
$$h(\alpha\wedge\omega,\eta)=\pm h(\omega,\alpha^\sharp\lrcorner\eta),$$ where $^\sharp$ is musical isomorphism associated with metric $h.$ And symbol of $\partial$ is just left wedge multiplication by (1,0)-form. So from authors computation it follows that $(dz_i)^\sharp=\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}_i}.$ And I see no reason why it should hold, cause $h$ was completely arbitrary.

Also B. Bigolin in his great paper "Gruppi di Aeppli" claims that Aeppli Laplacian, which is dual to Bott-Chern, is ellipitic. But it is completely without any proof [p. 284].

Can you clarify this and perhaps provide me with some good reference of complete proof of ellipticity?

Comment: In Kodaira-Spencer the metrics $g_t$ are just Hermitian, not necessarily Kahler, so their formula is correct in general. And with the standard definition of ellipticity, the formula of Kodaira-Spencer obviously implies ellipticity. So I don't see what you want, really.